# Pointer Arithmetic with argument passed by reference

Tags: c++, math, pointers, reference

As the title says, I need to modify the `i`<sup>th</sup> element of an array passed by reference...

I have the following situation:

```
function1(Node *&array, int i) {
   array = array +i; // crash!!!
   // operation on array[i]
}

function2() {
   Node** array;
   // filling the array bla bla bla
   function1(*(array+0), i);
}
```

The question is: what am I doing wrong when I write `array = array +i;`???

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You should specify what `// crash!!!` means, it's probably not crashing on that line. BTW, are you aware that you're modifying the incoming pointer (I mean in the calling scope)?

Comment: *Why* do you pass by reference?

Comment: So that I can modify the actual array and be more efficient...

Comment: You just can't change the reference after initializing it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your `function1` is designed incorrectly. Rather than attempting to pass an index, I would simply pass the `i`-th element.

```
function1(Node* array) {
    array->foo = ....
}
```

and call it like this:

```
function1(array[i]);
```

You really ought to get out of the habit of using the `+` operator as a means to index an array. Use the indexing `[]` syntax. I know that they can be interchangeable but the indexing syntax conveys intent.

---

In the comments you state that the index is in fact only known inside `function1` and is in fact not a parameter as stated in the question. In that case, pass `Node**` to `function1`.

Your code with the reference parameter modifies `array[0]` because that's the `Node*` reference that you passed in. But you want to modify the `i`-th node. If you pass a reference to a `Node*` then you can only modify that one object. In order to do what you need then you need to pass `Node**`.

Comment: I would do that, but unfortunately I can determine the index only within function 1...

Comment: That's not what your code says. Your code asks the caller to pass the index.

Comment: Yes I know, but that's not the case in the real program. I wrote that because I was concentrated on the other argument... sorry about that :p

Comment: In which case you need to pass Node** to the function

Comment: Do you mean as follows?

`function1(Node ** array) {
   // calculating i
   array = array +i; 
   // operation on array[i]
}

function2() {
   Node** array;
   // filling the array bla bla bla
   function1(array);
}`

Comment: I really urge you to stop using pointer arithmetic please. Use []. But basically, what you outline in the comment is reasonable. That said, wouldn't you be better with vector<> rather than raw pointers and arrays.

Comment: I need to use raw pointers unfortunately. But I'm not sure at the end what kind of argument I should pass you've suggested. You've meant: `function1(Node ** array) {
   // calculating i
   array[i] = blabla; 
   // operation on array[i]
}

function2() {
   Node** array;
   // filling the array bla bla bla
   function1(array);
}`? Thanks

Comment: Yes, that comment is what I mean

Answer (score 1):

Since `array` is declared as type pointer-to-pointer-to-Node, then the argument `*(array+0)` (which evaluates to `*array`) is type pointer-to-Node.  So you should declare

```
function1(Node *array, int i)
```

if you want to treat `array` as type pointer-to-Node within the function.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But isn'it more efficient if I pass the argument only by reference?

Comment: In this particular case, no.  You're passing a pointer either way.

Comment: Ok... but how shall I access the i-th element of the array within function1 if I declared how you've suggested? THanks again

Comment: `array` is of type pointer-to-Node.  You can access the ith `Node` as `array[i]` (preferred) or `*(array+i)` (harder to read).

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But if I do that and I write if(array[i] == NULL) Visual Studio tells me: No operand "==" found for that... :(

Comment: `array[i]` is of type `Node`.  It doesn't make sense to compare a `Node` with `==`.  Perhaps you can update your question with additional code and more detail about what you're trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're attempting to modify an array element, you only need to pass a pointer or reference to the array element you want to modify.

Example 1: Pass a reference to the element that you want to operate on.

```
function1(Node &element) {
   // operation on element
}

function2() {
   Node** array;
   // filling the array bla bla bla
   function1(array[0][i]);
}
```

Example 2: Pass a pointer to the element that you want to operate on.

```
function1(Node *element) {
   // operation on *element
}

function2() {
   Node** array;
   // filling the array bla bla bla
   function1(*array + i);
}
```

Example 3: Pass a pointer to the array and the index of the element.

```
function1(Node *array, int i) {
   Node *element = array + i;
   // operation on *element
}

function2() {
   Node** array;
   // filling the array bla bla bla
   function1(*array, i);
}
```

Example 4: As example 3 but using a local reference.

```
function1(Node *array, int i) {
   Node &element = array[i];
   // operation on element
}

function2() {
   Node** array;
   // filling the array bla bla bla
   function1(*array, i);
}
```

Example 5: As example 3 but reusing the parameter as a local variable. Note that this only works because array isn't a reference! You should probably avoid this style.

```
function1(Node *array, int i) {
   array += i;
   // operation on *array
}

function2() {
   Node** array;
   // filling the array bla bla bla
   function1(*array, i);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I believe I'm interested in example 1: the only thing is that I know the right the index only in function 1. To be more precise, I'll write a similar example of What I actually need to do. Thank you in advance! 
`function1(Node &array) {
   // calculating i
   Node *pointerToNewNode;
   // creating the new node
   j = 0;
   if(array[i][j] == NULL)
    array[i][j] = *pointer;
   else
    array[i][++j] = *pointer;
}

function2() {
   Node** array;
   // filling the array bla bla bla
   function1(array);
}`

Comment: @user1346664 `array[i][j]` can't equal `NULL` because it's a `Node`.

Comment: None of these examples are appropriate. `Node**` is an array of pointers to `Node`. It is not an array of `Node`.